# loop with requests.get and avoid timeout errors

Tags: loops, python-requests

I am trying to get scrape information.

I goto the introduction page to determine the number of search results. Often, the results occur over >1 page, and as such, I need to refresh and run another requests in a loop. On a few occasions an error occurs in the extra requests, or it hangs.

I am curious if there is a way to check a request, if it fails, then try again, and if it still fails, log it and go to the next one

Here is a sample script:

```
t=.3
urls=['https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.google.com/'] #list of upto 200 urls
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=t) 
    t=t+10
    i=i-1
```

running this returns a timeout occasionally, and the processing stops. My workaround is to print the url that failed, and then rerun, updating the list manually.

[image]

I would like to find a way that if a request error occurs, the response retries 5x, and if it fails, logs and stores the failed url, then goes onto the next one, so that I can try the failed urls at a later stage

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Python in a while, but I'm pretty sure that this will work.

```
t=.3
urls=['https://stackoverflow.com/','https://www.google.com/'] #list of upto 200 urls
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    try:
       response = requests.get(url, timeout=t) 
    except:
        # if the request fails: try again
        try:
           response = requests.get(url, timeout=t)
        except:
            # if the request fails again: do nothing (continue to the next url)
            pass
     t=t+10
     i=i-1
```